# i made a code for knapsack problem but the system wont tell me whats wrong in my code only tells its wrong

Tags: python

*this is my first time posting and have been told that this place is like heaven so Hey everyone :)
i have this problem with an assigment the  knapsack problem which says
A thief finds much more loot than his bag can fit.Help him to find the most valuable combination of items assuming that any fraction of a loot item can be put into his bag.The first line of the input contains the number n of items and the capacity W of a knapsack. The next n lines define the values and weights of the items . The i-th line contains integers vi and wi—the value and the weight of i-th item, respectively.
and i made this code might not be the easiest to read as im a beginer but basicly
n=number of items   back= the storage limit of the bag  and three lists and x is the ratio of value to weight and tot=is the total value
this is the error I get
Failed case #5/13: Wrong answer
wrong output format: list index out of range
hope u guys can help me and one day I be the one tha helps

````
n,back=map(int,input().split())
for i in range(n):
    v,w=map(int,input().split())
    values.append(v)
    weight.append(w)
    x.append(v/w)
u=x.index(max(x))
while x !=[]:
    u=x.index(max(x))
    if weight[u]< back:
        back-=weight[u]
        tot+=values[u]
        values.pop(u)
        weight.pop(u)
        x.pop(u)

    elif weight[u]== back:
        back-=weight[u]
        tot+=values[u]

        break
    elif weight[u]>back:
        l=weight[u]/back
        tot+=values[u]/l

        break
    else:
        print("There is something wrong")
        break
print(round(float(tot),0))```
````